# p:dialog sendo chamado por vários buttons no sistema

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, dialog

Pessoal eu tenho uma dialog (do `primefaces`) que confirma o número de CEP e após o usuário informar o número da residência neste `dialog` os campos endereço, bairro, cep, cidade e uf tem que serem preenchidos no formulário. O problema é que este `dialog` pode ser chamado em vários locais do sistema onde se têm CEP para validar, num mesmo formulário se têm mais de um CEP. Então como eu consigo fazer com que o botão Confirma do `dialog` execute métodos diferentes e `beans` diferentes ?

PS: Eu estou usando `JSF+PrimeFaces`.

Segue o código:

Dialog:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<p:dialog widgetVar="cepConfirmDlg" modal="true" responsive="true" header="Confirmar Endereço" resizable="false" width="630" closable="false" >
    <p:panelGrid id="panelMensagem" columns="1" layout="grid" class="semBorda" rendered="#{buscaCEPMB.renderizaPanel = 1}">
    </p:panelGrid>>
    <p:panelGrid id="panelConfirma" columns="1" layout="grid" class="semBorda" rendered="#{buscaCEPMB.renderizaPanel = 3}"  >
    <p:panelGrid id="cepConfirmPanel" columns="1" layout="grid" class="semBorda">
    <p:messages/>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:outputLabel value="Logradouro: "/><p:outputLabel value="#{buscaCEPMB.viaEndereco.logradouro}" class="labelFine" />
    </h:panelGroup><h:panelGroup>
        <p:outputLabel value="Complemento: "/><p:outputLabel value="#{buscaCEPMB.viaEndereco.complemento}" class="labelFine" />
    </h:panelGroup><h:panelGroup>
        <p:outputLabel value="Bairro: "/><p:outputLabel value="#{buscaCEPMB.viaEndereco.bairro}" class="labelFine" />
    </h:panelGroup><h:panelGroup>
        <p:outputLabel value="   CEP: "/><p:outputLabel value="#{buscaCEPMB.viaEndereco.cep}" class="labelFine" />
    </h:panelGroup><h:panelGroup>
        <p:outputLabel value="Cidade/UF: "/><p:outputLabel value="#{buscaCEPMB.viaEndereco.localidade}/#{buscaCEPMB.viaEndereco.uf}" class="labelFine" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:fieldset>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" class="semBorda" >
                <p:outputLabel value="Endereço" for="confEndereco"/>
                <p:inputText id="confEndereco" value="#{cepMB.endereco}" maxlength="75" styleClass="Wid90" required="true" requiredMessage="É Obrigatório Informar o Endereço do Imóvel!"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Nr. e Complemento" for="confNr"/>
                <p:inputText id="confNr" value="#{cepMB.nrComp}" maxlength="25" required="true" requiredMessage="É Obrigatório Informar o Número do Imóvel!"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Bairro" for="confBairro"/>
                <p:inputText id="confBairro" value="#{cepMB.bairro}" maxlength="25" styleClass="Wid60" required="true" requiredMessage="É Obrigatório Informar o Bairro do Imóvel!"/>
               </p:panelGrid>   
        </p:fieldset>
    </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panelGrid>>
```

Uma tela `form` com `include` do dialog e com 2 botões para a procura de CEP (eu preciso chamar e confirmar o CEP no endereço residencial como no comercial:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
                xmlns:oz="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/ozelo/componentes"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

    <ui:define name="content">
 <p:panel id="formCliPF">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" class="semBorda" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-1, ui-grid-col-11">
           <div class="SoftBlueBack DispInlBlock" style="padding:20px 10px;">
                <i style="margin: 0 auto;" class="oz-PFM Blue Fs100"></i>
                <p></p>
                <p:rating stars="5" cancel="false" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.star}" />
           </div>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" class="semBorda">
      <p:outputLabel for="apelido" value="Apelido:" />
      <p:inputText id="apelido" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.apelido}" maxlength="25"/>
      <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
      <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.nome}" maxlength="120" styleClass="Wid100" requiredMessage="Nome do Cliente É Obrigatório!"/>
          </p:panelGrid>
    <p:outputLabel/>   
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" class="semBorda">
    <p:panelGrid columns="3" layout="grid" class="semBorda">
      <p:outputLabel for="rg" value="RG:" />
        <p:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF:" />
        <p:outputLabel/>
      <p:inputText id="rg" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.rg}" />
        <p:inputMask id="cpf" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.cpf}" mask="999.999.999-99" />
    </p:panelGrid>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" class="semBorda">
        <p:outputLabel for="sexo" value="Sexo:" />
        <p:outputLabel for="dtNasc" value="Data Nascimento:"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="sexo" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.sexo}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fem." itemValue="F" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Masc." itemValue="M" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:calendar id="dtNasc" locale="pt" navigator="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.dtNasc}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:fieldset>
        <p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid" class="semBorda"> 
            <p:outputLabel value="Telefones:" /><p:outputLabel/><p:outputLabel/><p:outputLabel/>
        <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.tel1}" styleClass="telMask" />
        <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.tel2}" styleClass="telMask" />
        <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.tel3}" styleClass="telMask" />
        <p:inputText value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.tel4}" styleClass="telMask" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:panelGrid columns="3" layout="grid" class="semBorda" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-3, ui-grid-col-6">
        <p:outputLabel for="telcial" value="Tel. Cial.:" />
        <p:outputLabel for="nextel" value="Nextel:" />
        <p:outputLabel for="email" value="e-Mail:" />
        <p:inputText id="telcial" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.cel}" styleClass="telMask" />
        <p:inputText id="nextel" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.nextel}" />
        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.email}" styleClass="Wid90"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
        <p:outputLabel for="endereco" value="Endereço:" />
       <p:panel id="endRes">
        <p:inputText id="endereco" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.endereco}" maxlength="100" styleClass="Wid90"/>
       <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" class="semBorda"> 
        <p:outputLabel for="bairro" value="Bairro:" />
        <p:outputLabel for="cep" value="CEP:" />
        <p:inputText id="bairro" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.bairro}" maxlength="25" styleClass="Wid90"/>
        <h:panelGroup>
        <p:inputMask id="cep" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.cep}" mask="99999-999" /><p:spacer width="5"/>

        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-envelope Fs16 White" value="cep" process="endRes"  action="#{clienteMB.buscaCEPRes()}" update="endRes growl" />
        </h:panelGroup>
       </p:panelGrid>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" class="semBorda" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-10, ui-grid-col-2">
        <p:outputLabel for="cidade" value="Cidade:" />
        <p:outputLabel for="uf" value="UF:" />
        <p:inputText id="cidade" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.cidade}" styleClass="Wid90"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="uf" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.uf}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{clienteMB.ufs}"  />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panelGrid>
       </p:panel>
        <p:fieldset id="endCom">
    <p:outputLabel for="empresa" value="Empresa Nome:"/>
    <p:inputText id="empresa" value="#{clienteMB.cliFinSel.empresaNome}" maxlength="60" styleClass="Wid90"/>
    <p:outputLabel for="empresaEnd" value="Endereço:"/>
    <p:inputText id="empresaEnd" value="#{clienteMB.cliFinSel.empresaEnd}" maxlength="100" styleClass="Wid90"/>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" class="semBorda"> 
    <p:outputLabel for="empresaBai" value="Bairro:"/>
    <p:outputLabel for="empresaCep" value="CEP:" />
    <p:inputText id="empresaBai" value="#{clienteMB.cliFinSel.empresaBai}" maxlength="25" styleClass="Wid90"/>
    <h:panelGroup><p:inputMask id="empresaCep" value="#{clienteMB.cliFinSel.empresaCEP}" mask="99999-999" /><p:spacer width="5"/>
      <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-envelope Fs16 White" value="cep" process="endCom"  action="#{clienteMB.buscaCEPCom()}" update="endCom growl" /></h:panelGroup>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" class="semBorda" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-10, ui-grid-col-2">
    <p:outputLabel for="empresaCid" value="Cidade:"/>
    <p:outputLabel for="empresaUf" value="UF:"/>
    <p:inputText id="empresaCid" value="#{clienteMB.cliFinSel.empresaCidade}" maxlength="50" styleClass="Wid90"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="empresaUf" value="#{clienteMB.cliFinSel.empresaUF}" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{clienteMB.ufs}"  />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:panelGrid columns="3" layout="grid" class="semBorda" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-4, ui-grid-col-3, ui-col-4">
    <p:outputLabel for="empresaTel" value="Telefone:"/>
    <p:inputText id="empresaTel" value="#{clienteMB.cliSel.cel}" styleClass="telMask" />
    </p:panelGrid>
    </p:fieldset>   

    </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panelGrid>
    </div>  
        <p:messages />
  <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="fa fa-times Fs16 White" styleClass="Fright RedButton" action="#{clienteMB.doCancela()}" />
  <p:commandButton value="Salvar" icon="fa fa-check Fs16 White" class="Fright" action="#{clienteMB.doAddCli}" process="formCliPF" update="formCliPF" />
 </p:panel>
    <ui:include src="../cepConfirma.xhtml"/>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

O `ClienteMB` que controla o form e chama o `CepMB` que mostra o dialog:

```
public void buscaCEPRes() {
     cepMB.confirmaCEP(cliSel.getCep(), cliSel.getEndereco(), cliSel.getCidade(), cliSel.getUf());
}

public void buscaCEPCom() {
     cepMB.confirmaCEP(cliSel.getEmpCep(), cliSel.getEmpEndereco(), cliSel.getEmpCidade(), cliSel.getEmpUf());
}
```

O `CepMB` controla a dialog com a busca de cep:

```
    public void confirmaCEP(String nrCEP, String valEndereco, String valCidade, String valUf) throws IOException,IllegalArgumentException {
        ViaCEPClient client = new ViaCEPClient();
        viaEndereco = null;
        listaViaEndereco = null;
        okCEP = false;
try{
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nrCEP)){   
           viaEndereco = client.getEndereco(nrCEP);
if (endereco != null) {carregaEnderecoParaConfirma();
}else{createFacesErrorMessage("CEP Inválido", "Não Foi Possível Localizar CEP!");}
   }else{ if (!StringUtils.isNotBlank(valCidade)||!StringUtils.isNotBlank(valUf)){
    createFacesErrorMessage("Dados Inválidos", "É Necessário Informar no Mínimo a Cidade e o Estado!");
}else{
     listaViaEndereco = client.getEnderecos(valUf, valCidade, valEndereco);
  if (listaViaEndereco != null) {carregaListaEnderecoParaConfirma();
}else{createFacesErrorMessage("Endereço Inválido", "Não Foi Possível Localizar CEP!");}
    }
}
 }catch (IOException e){
   createFacesErrorMessage("Erro I/O", "Não Foi Possível Conectar com o Servidor de CEP!");  
 }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        createFacesErrorMessage("CEP Inválido", e.getMessage());
 }


    }

public void carregaEnderecoParaConfirma(){
    endereco = viaEndereco.getLogradouro();
    bairro = viaEndereco.getBairro();
    nrComp = "";
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:cepConfirmPanel");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('cepConfirmDlg').show();");
    }
```

O metodo do botão Confirma do dialog não fiz.

Comment: Olá Ozelo, poderia postar um [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrando o problema? Fiquei com a impressão que você precisa mesmo é um [*Composite Component*](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/) para esses *buttons* em que você possa indicar a `action` e demais detalhes dessa sua *dialog* de CEP. Porém só dá para ter ideia com um exemplo de código.

Comment: A dialog vai ser chamada por bean diferentes ou beans diferentes vão ser processados durante a sua chamada? Se for o primeiro caso dá pra resolver usando polimorfismo.

Comment: Anthony, os botões que chamam o dialog que muda e não o botão Confirma do dialog, então acho que o Composite Component não se aplicaria nisso. Giuliana, quando você fala em polimorfismo neste caso seria passar qual cliente.endereco, cliente.bairro, cliente.cep... para o CepMB?

Comment: Olhem um outro caso: suponha que eu tenha uma dialog com um dataTable nela listando todos os meus cliente e eu seleciono um cliente para que seja atribuido a um determinado campo. Uma vez esta dialog sera chamada para atribuir ao Cliente do Pedido de Venda, outra tela chama para atribuir o Cliente para cadastro de indicação, outras vezes para diversos outros atributos Cliente do sistema. Como vou conseguir que o botão Confirma deste dialog "saiba" para qual atributo eu desejo referenciar?

Answer (score 0):

Não acredito ser a melhor alternativa, pois pode atrapalhar e muito a manutenção, já que vc começa a jogar um pouco da programação para a View.

Mas vc pode passar um objeto como parâmetro do método, ou mesmo setar um valor no Bean antes de executar a ação. Em ambos os casos, vc pode construir um Objeto do padrão [Command](http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-command-em-java/26456) e a execução fica a cargo desse objeto. Com isso, mesmo que o Bean seja o mesmo, o Command já vai estar preparado para executar o melhor método para cada área.